# tmux bind semicolon

Tags: bind, tmux

Is there some way I can bind ; (\059) to a command in tmux?

By default, it is bound to last-pane; however, I would like to rebind it to select-pane -R.

I have tried putting the following in my .tmux.conf, but none seem to work:

1. "bind \059 select-pane -R" -> tmux reports "unkown key \059", but after ignoring the warning, ";" sometimes does work as intended.
2. "bind ; select-pane -R" -> tmux reports "usage: bind-key ..."
3. "bind ';' select-pane -R" -> tmux reports "usage: bind-key ..."

I'm using the first option now, but I'd like to do it correctly so I don't have a warning appear every time I start tmux.

Answer (score 7):

Semi-colon is also used as a command separator in tmux, so in order to bind it, you need to escape it:

```
bind-key \; select-pane -R
```

Answer (score 2):

*tmux* quoting is a bit quirky; it looks very much like Bourne shell-style quoting, but it has subtle differences.

The only thing that works to escape a trailing (or lone) semicolon is a backslash:

```
bind \; select-pane -R
```

The relevant part of the man page:

> A literal semicolon may
>        be included by escaping it with a backslash (for example, when specifying
>        a command sequence to bind-key).

A trailing, unescaped semicolon acts as a separator between *tmux* commands.

*tmux* is showing you the `bind-key` usage (for your examples numbered 2 and 3) because when the semicolon is unescaped (even when it is quoted, unlike the shell), the line is parsed as two commands: `bind` and `select-pane -R`. The first of those commands is incomplete (`bind-key` requires at least two arguments: a key and a command).

Your `\059` attempt (your example numbered 1) was likewise failing to adjust the bindings because the octal syntax is not supported when specifying keys. The default binding for <kbd>Prefix</kbd> <kbd>;</kbd> is `last-pane`, which may end up moving a pane to the right (i.e. what `select-pane -R` does), but only if the next pane to the right happens to be the previously active pane.

Comment: Does this approach also work to bind the `#`? It normally indicates a comment (at least vim thinks all .conf files follow the `#` is comment rule)

Comment: @StevenLu: The semicolon is a bit of a special case. You can use quotes to protect `#`: `bind-key '#' display-message octothorpe`.

Comment: Oh cool, thanks. Hey free +15 points if you post the same answer on the question I made for this.

Comment: @ChrisJohnsen, what if I want to do `bind -n C-; select-pane -l`? It doesn't work if I escape the semicolon. What do I do?