# How to use Ctrl-semicolon for prefix in tmux?

Tags: tmux

I want to use Ctrl-semicolon for tmux's prefix. But my conf doesn't work.

```
 unbind-key C-b  
 set-option -g prefix C-\;
```

I found a similar article. But it's not for the prefix.
[tmux bind semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665802/tmux-bind-semicolon)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Terminal can't register a `Ctrl-;` keystroke. It's just not a valid character. If you look at the control characters in the below ascii table, you'll see `Ctrl-;` is not on the list.

[image]

I'm on OS X and when I type `Ctrl - ;` in the (terminal and in a "desktop" program) I get a bell sound indicating the character is not recognized or something.

As for the "favorite" prefix key: from what I saw reading other people's `.tmux.conf` files, `Ctrl-a` is the most popular choice. This makes sense because:

- `Ctrl-a` was the default for [GNU Screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/), tmux predecessor
- it's much easier to type than the default `Ctrl-b` especially when you [remap caps lock to ctrl](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?RemapCapsLock).

The downside to using `Ctrl-a` is that you can't use the same key in bash or vim, but that's easily solved by having the following binding in `.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key 'C-a' send-prefix
```

With that, pressing the `Ctrl-a` twice will send the same character to the underlying program (eg bash or vim).

Comment: Binding "Ctrl+;" is quite easy in macOS, what iTerm can for example do is make it send an unique escape code that terminals programs can understand. Unfortunately I'm not really sure yet how you can do it in linux/other terminals programs

Comment: Given protocols to support mouse events, why not extended keyboard events? Sounds like a project!

Comment: This looks like it! https://sw.kovidgoyal.net/kitty/keyboard-protocol/

Answer (score 6):

As others said, you can't bind to `Ctrl-;` because it's not a valid character.

I like that prefix because it's really easy to press when CapsLock is remapped to Ctrl.

My workaround, for Linux, was to remap `Ctrl-;` to `Ctrl-B` at the xkb level.
[Xkb](https://www.x.org/wiki/XKB/) is the Xorg subsystem which handles keyboard layouts.

I'm using the us layout, so I modified the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/us` at line 42:

```
key <AC10> {     [ semicolon,    colon           ]       };
```

to

```
//  key <AC10> {     [ semicolon,    colon           ]       };
key <AC10> {                                                  
   type="BABEL_CONTROL_LEVEL3",                               
   symbols[Group1]= [ semicolon, colon, b ]                   
};
```

This tells Xkb to generate for `AC10` (the 10-th button in the C row) semicolon at level 1 (no modifiers), colon at level 2 (shift modifier) and b at level 3 (Ctrl modifier).

Level 3 in Xkb is not activated by Ctrl generally, for this reason I created a new key type, which I called `BABEL_CONTROL_LEVEL3`. You need to put its definition in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/types/pc`:

```
type "BABEL_CONTROL_LEVEL3" {
    modifiers = Shift+Control;
    map[Shift] = Level2;
    map[Control] = Level3;
    level_name[Level1] = "Base";
    level_name[Level2] = "Shift";
    level_name[Level3] = "Control";
};
```

You'll need to restart X or reboot.

List of resources which helped me with this:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/205226/xkb-make-ctrlbackspace-behave-as-delete
- https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Custom%20keyboard%20layout%20definitions
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/X_KeyBoard_extension

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use control-semicolon, you can try AutoHotkey.

This is my tmux & autohotkey settings.

Tmux:

```
set-option -g prefix 'C-\'
```

AutoHotkey:

```
^;::
    Send ^{\}
return
```