# Tmux: How do I bind C-; as the prefix?

Tags: tmux, prefix

Since this is an un-used key combination for me, and because ; sits nicely under my right pinky finger, I think Ctrl-; would make a nice, quick prefix for tmux. However, I can't figure out how to bind it. I've tried:

```
set -g prefix C-;
unbind C-b
bind C-;
```

And variations, such as C-\;  'C-;'  'C-\;'

None work.

Thanks!
--Myles

Duplicate: I found the answer here.

[How to use Ctrl-semicolon for prefix in tmux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680362/how-to-use-ctrl-semicolon-for-prefix-in-tmux)

Apparently ctrl-; doesn't even have an ASCII code.

Comment: What does your terminal send when you press `ctrl-;`?

Comment: Duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680362/how-to-use-ctrl-semicolon-for-prefix-in-tmux

Comment: I don't know. But your question gave me the answer! I am using iTerm2. I can map ctrl-; to send something more palatable to tmux (like ctrl-\ that I see a lot of people using). Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Ctrl-semicolon for prefix in tmux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680362/how-to-use-ctrl-semicolon-for-prefix-in-tmux)