# Tmux remap prompt for command -- Ctrl-b + :

Tags: tmux

The goal is to be able to type `Ctrl-b + ;` instead of `Ctrl - b + :` to activate the tmux command prompt.

I can't figure out how create this particular binding.

I know how to use `bind-keys` to have a shortcut to execute commands to creating new windows etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tmux bind semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665802/tmux-bind-semicolon)

Answer (score 0):

via shell:

```
tmux bind-key -T prefix "\;" command-prompt
```

In `.tmux.conf` configuration or `tmux command-prompt`:

```
bind \; command-prompt
```

For explanation, see [tmux bind semicolon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12665802/1396928). It's escaped because it's a command separator in tmux commands.